# C# generic interface specialization

Tags: c#

I wonder if it is in any way possible to specialize generic interface methods somehow in C#? I have found similar questions, but nothing exactly like this. Now I suspect that the answer is "No, you can't" but I would like to have it confirmed.

What I have is something like the following.

```
public interface IStorage
{
    void Store<T>(T data);
}

public class Storage : IStorage
{
    public void Store<T>(T data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic");
    }

    public void Store(int data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specific");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IStorage i = new Storage();
        i.Store("somestring"); // Prints Generic
        i.Store(1); // Prints Generic
        Storage s = (Storage)i;
        s.Store("somestring"); // Prints Generic
        s.Store(1); // Prints Specific
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it use the specialized version of Store when called through the interface? And if not, does anyone know the exact reason why C# treats Generic arguments this way?

Edit:
The issue could be worked around if it wasn't so that C# cannot resolve template arguments in more than one step.

```
void Foo<T>(T t)
{
    SubFoo(t);
}

void SubFoo<T>(T t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Generic");
}

void SubFoo(int t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Specific");
}
```

A call to Foo(1) here will print "Generic" as well, shouldn't the compiler be able to resolve this? Or does the JIT prevent this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do template specialization in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Overload resolution is performed at compile-time, not at run-time based on the actual type of the passed value.

```
IStorage i = new Storage();
i.Store("somestring"); // Prints Generic
i.Store(1); // Prints Generic
```

This will always call the "generic" method, because there is only one overload of `Store` in `IStorage` and the compiler doesn't know that `i` actually contains a `Storage` object. How can the compiler know about the other overload in `Storage`?

```
Storage s = (Storage)i;
s.Store("somestring"); // Prints Generic
s.Store(1); // Prints Specific
```

Here, the compiler knows that `s` contains a `Storage` object (or one deriving from `Storage`), because `s` is declared that way. So it sees two overloads. It chooses the specific overload for `int` values, because overload resolution rules say to prefer specific overloads over generic overloads.

---

It's technically possible to determine `typeof(T)` in the generic method at run-time and forward the method call to a specific method. But if you think about it, this doesn't make a lot of sense. A generic method means that the same implementation works for arguments of different, unrelated types. If you want different implementations for different types, you shouldn't use generics for this.

---

```
void Foo<T>(T t)
{
    SubFoo(t);
}

void SubFoo<T>(T t);
void SubFoo(int t);
```

Generics work quite a bit different from C++ templates. The C# compiler compiles Foo only once -- to a generic method. Remember: generic means same implementation for different types. The C# compiler does not know at compile-time if T is going to be an `int` or a `string` or any other type. So the only possible implementation of Foo that works for any T is to call SubFoo<T>. If one of the SubFoo overloads would be called depending on T, the implementation of Foo wouldn't be the same for all T any more.

Comment: What's the point of the generic T? Why not just type the data parameter as object and test if (data is int)?

Comment: That makes alot of sense when thinking about it from the compilers perspective. Though I have a vague memory C++ could accomplish this somehow, though I couldn't get it working now. I'll edit my question a bit to explain a further problem that prevents a workaround to this, I hope you can explain that as well, though I will accept this answer :)

Comment: I would've expected it to work more similarly to C++ templates since the information about the call to Foo is available at compile time I had expected it to call Foo<int> when an int is passed and Foo<string> when a string passed which would then in turn call SubFoo(someInt) and SubFoo(someString) like C++ does as C++ templates is compile time resolved as well.

Comment: Jamie: Thinking like that you could as well scrap generics, since you can always replace it with object and type casting. But then you scrap type safety and you get a performance loss as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why Generic code-based specialization make a lot of sense in real world and in particular, in extension methods ?

I will take an example on collections because evrybody kowns more or less .NET collections.

I will take the simple example of the `.Last(this IEnumerable<<T>> coll)` extension method. In .NET Framework, this method use in-code type specialization.

First, concerning the benefit of type specialization, this example is quite clear. Some enumerable collections need to scan the whole collection and return the last element, array based one need only to return the last allocated element of the array, many linked list have a pointer to the last element... So implementing a generic with type specialization can make the `.Last()` method by far more efficient.

Second because this method is static, having many implementations for each collection type or interfaces wouldn't solve the problem of right method selection. In effect, selection of the right method is done at compile time based on apparent type of coll object. If you imagine, you want to apply consecutive extensions methods on a `List<<T>>`, the first one may not need many per collection type specialized implementations and use a single one based on `IEnumerable<<T>>`. So even if we have a `.Last(this List<<T>> coll)`, the first non specialized extension method will return a `IEnumerable<<T>>` and the specialized `.Last(this List<<T>> coll)` will not be used for the `List<<T>>`.

So if your code use external assemblies (even .NET Framework itself), if you have to provide a solution in two weeks to a complex architectural problem ... you leave the domain of the perfection to enter in the real world. And generic type specialization become an not to ignore option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of compile-time overload resolution you may as well extend the interface with a method that takes an `int`:

```
public interface IStorage
{
    void Store<T>(T data);
}

public interface IIntStorage: IStorage
{
    void Store(int data);
}

public class Storage : IIntStorage
{
    public void Store<T>(T data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic");
    }

    public void Store(int data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specific");
    }
}
```

Now if you call `Store(1)` through the `IIntStorage` interface it will use the specialized method (similar to how you called `Storage`'s method directly), but if you call it through `IStorage` it will still use the generic version.

Comment: I wanted a common interface and not a specialized class for each type :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public interface IStorage<T>
{
    void Store(object data);
    void Store<T>(T data);
}

public class Storage : IStorage<int>
{
    public void Store(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic");
    }

    public void Store(int data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specific");
    }
}
```

You've typed i as IStorage and that interface doesn't define the overloaded Store method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by introducing additional type information (e.g. implementing an interface). Here is an example.

```
// no need to modify the original interface
public interface IStorage
{
    void Store<T>(T data);
}
```

Implementation with specialization based on a generic interface

```
public class Storage : IStorage,
    Storage.ISpecializedFor<int>,
    Storage.ISpecializedFor<double>
{
    // a private interface to provide additional type info
    private interface ISpecializedFor<T>
    {
        void Store(T data);
    }

    public void Store<T>(T data)
    {
        // resolve specialization
        if (this is ISpecializedFor<T> specialized)
        {
            specialized.Store(data);
        }
        else
        {
            // unspecialized implementation goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Unspecialized");
        }
    }

    // specialized implementation
    void ISpecializedFor<int>.Store(int data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specialized for int");
    }

    void ISpecializedFor<double>.Store(double data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specialized for double");
    }
}
```

Results

```
void Main()
{
    IStorage storage = new Storage();

    storage.Store("hello"); // prints "Unspecialized"
    storage.Store(42); // prints "Specialized for int"
    storage.Store(1.0); // prints "Specialized for double"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because C# generics are runtime templates in some circumstances you should use runtime specialization. For example, in generic static methods, inheritance and interfaces aren't usable. If you want to specialize generic static methods - in particular extension methods -  you have to detect the type in code with constructs like :

if (typeof(T)==typeof(bool))

For specialization of reference types (like string for example), and an argument T data, you would prefere:

string s = data as string;
if (s!=null)

In this example, a problem come from conversion between T and bool in specialized code : You know that T is bool but the language doesn't allow conversion between those types. The solution come from the object type: an object can be casted to any type (conversion is checked at runtime and not at compile time in this case). so if you have

T data;

you can write:

bool b=(bool)(object)data;
data=(T)(object)b;

This isn't perfect: If type equality is quite fast, in some circumstances you have to test if T is a derived type of a specified type (a little longer). And when T is a value type like bool, cast to object and then back to type mean value type boxing/unboxing and runtime type check for reference types. Runtime optimiser can remove these non necessary steps but I cannot say if they do so.

Depending on the usage of your static method, remember that you can apply where T: ... restrictions on parametrized types. And that default(T) return false for boolean, zero for numeric base types and null for reference types.

Runtime specialization implies an additional test steps and boxing/unboxing/runtime type checks, so it isn't the panacea but allows too specialize generic methods in an acceptable time in many circumstances: For long operation (in particular for optimization) or when hiding or grouping of types complexity management is more important than performances.

Comment: Before casting from `T` or checking the type of an instance of `T`, it's a good idea to check the type of `T` itself.  If `T` is a non-nullable value type, an storage location of type `T` will hold an instance of type `T`; calling `GetType()` on the thing in the storage location would require boxing it, but checking the type of `T` would not.  Note that even if `T` is not a value type, it is possible that a storage location of type `T` will hold a reference to a boxed value-type instance.