# C# How to call function from generic code

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to make a generic type dispatcher (C++ like), but it looks like I can't call a function with a generic parameter:

Sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoSomething(1);
    }

    static void DoSomething<T>(T value)
    {
        //error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'int'
        DoSomethingElse(value);
    }

    static void DoSomethingElse(int a)
    {
        Console.Write("int\n");
    }

    static void DoSomethingElse(float a)
    {
        Console.Write("float\n");
    }
}
```

Can you please explain why I can't call `DoSomethingElse` from `DoSomething`?
How may I forward `value` to another function that accepts that specific type?

Comment: because do something else is a different type...

Comment: @johnny5 `DoSomethingElse` is a function that can be called with any `int` and `value` is of type `int`. I don't understand your comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# generic interface specialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229084/c-sharp-generic-interface-specialization)

Comment: @Felics No, `value` is of type `T`, not `int`.  The compiler has of course already told you as much.

Comment: @Felics, at compile time it doesn't know it can do that, you can check explicitly for the type int and then cast but that seems a bit wierd

Comment: Basically, generics work very different to templates. In .NET, the IL **knows about T** - it isn't boiled away by the compiler.

Comment: @Servy isn't `T` an alias for `int`? In C++ `std::is_same_v<T, int>` is true...

Comment: Why is this necessary? If DoSomethingElse() is called directly, the correct polymorph will be found at compile time.  To do this at runtime, I think you'll have to add some logic.  This feels like an XY problem, though.  What is it you're really trying to do here?

Comment: @Felics To the compiler it's it's own type, distinct from every other type.

Comment: @Felics no, `T` is `T`. The `T` can in theory be anything, and the IL preserves that. You could have `DoSomething(1)` and `DoSomething("abc")`, but that would still be **one** (single) IL method, not 2

Comment: @MarcL. this is just a simple example to reduce the real problem to something suite for a SO question. The function will dispatch the value to different functions based on a second parameter.

Comment: @MarcGravell so basically it will be one function, not 2 (or more) as in C++...

Comment: The key thing about generics is that you are conceptually doing **the same** thing with each T. Choosing an overload based on the type is the **opposite** of "generic"

Comment: @Felics yes, one function; you can see that using ILDasm or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the cleanest way to deal with it, but you can cast to `dynamic`.
The problem is, if you don't have a method implemented for whatever type `T` is, it will crash at runtime.  You may be able to narrow that problem a bit by adding a [constraint to your generic parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

```
static void DoSomething<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    DoSomethingElse((dynamic)value);
}
```

Comment: Another problem here is that this introduces boxing and the DLR - but yes, it will work

Comment: This is what I wanted. Unfortunately this will give a runtime error instead of a compile time error in the case DoSomethingElse is missing...

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you explain what boxing is? edit, nvm, found a good resource.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Without any constraints, you are only permitted to do activities that you could do if `value` is of type object.  You can use the `is` and `as` keywords to work around this.

If you add a where constraint such as `where T : IComparable`, you are permitted to use methods and properties that meet the constraint.

i.e.  with the IComparable constraint, you could call `value.CompareTo(x)`

```
static void DoSomething<T>(T value)
{
    if (value is int)
    {
        DoSomethingElse((value as int?).Value);
    }
    else if (value is float)
    {
        DoSomethingElse((value as float?).Value);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("No handler for type " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```