# Generics and "One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type" Error

Tags: c#, operators, operator-overloading

When declaring a binary operator, at least one of the operand types must be the containing type. This sounds a good design decision in general. However, I didn't expect the following code to cause this error:

```
public class Exp<T>
{
    public static Exp<int> operator +(Exp<int> first, Exp<int> second)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What is the problem with this operator? Why this case falls into operator overloading restrictions of c#? is it dangerous to allow this kind of declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the containing type is `Exp<T>`, not `Exp<int>`. What you are trying to do here is specialization *a la* C++, which is not possible in C#.

Comment: so the problem here is not that the operands are not related to containing types, which can be dangerous, but that it's not permitted to have "specializations"?

Comment: Yes. What you are trying to do looks totally like C++ *template specialization* which is not directly possible in C#. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

You are in a class of type `Exp<T>`, and neither of the parameters in the operator are `Exp<T>`, they're both `Exp<int>`.

Read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/genericnumerics.aspx) for the suggested way around this.

Comment: I know that the types are different. In the case they are not related, I understand it can be dangerous. But here, it looks more like a limitation imposed by generics than a design safe-guard.
Thank you for the suggested article!