# Overload generic method from interface

Tags: c#

I have an interface with the generic method:

```
interface IConverter
{
    void Convert<T>(T value);
}
```

I would like to implement it for any type, but also I know that for `string` the method logic can be simplified, so I'd like to overload it specifically for `string` (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525190/overloading-generic-methods)):

```
class Converter : IConverter
{
    public void Convert<T>(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Method " + value);
    }

    public void Convert(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String Method " + value);
    }
}
```

That works fine when I have instance of `Converter` and call method directly. The code

```
var converter = new Converter();
converter.Convert("ABC");
converter.Convert(123);
```

outputs

```
String Method ABC
Generic Method 123
```

However, when I work with interface (like in any app with DI), I can't call my overload for `string`. The code

```
var converter = (IConverter)new Converter();
converter.Convert("ABC");
converter.Convert(123);
```

outputs:

```
Generic Method ABC
Generic Method 123
```

Is there anyway to accomplish calling of `string` overloaded method **without type checking** like

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    ...
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cast `converter` to `IConverter`, so there is only one method visible on your `converter` variable: `Convert<T>(T value)`.

You can overcome this by adding `Convert(string)` to the interface, or don't cast to the interface at all and keep using your `Converter` class. Only then the other method will be visible.

Comment: Ok. But from my understanding JIT will create string version of method. And such string version is already exists implemented by me...

Comment: Still it uses the method known from the interface. It doesn't magically call another method just because it looks the same.

Comment: @KyryloM: JITter will take the generic `Convert<T>` method and create a JITtted specialized `Convert<string>` method, like it's supposed to do. Your other method is, as far as C# is concerned, the same as having a method with a completely different name.

Comment: Probably you are right. I've checked the full method name from the stack trace. For the generic version its a `Converter.Convert[T](T)`, for string method - `Converter.Convert(System.String)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways,

Either you include that method in your interface like

```
interface IConverter
{
    void Convert<T>(T value);
    void Convert(string value);
}
```

Have that method specific to `string` created as extension method

```
public static void Convert(this string str, string value)
{
  // code here
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean `public static void Convert(this IConverter str, ...`?

Comment: @Jcl, NO, I mean what I said. It's a extension method for the `string` type

Comment: Then it's just not the same... you'd need to do: `stringVariable.Convert(anotherString);`... the OP wants: `iconverterVariable.Convert(someString)`

Comment: @Jcl, didn't I mentioned it's an alternative along with including the method itself part of interface definition

Comment: again, it's an alternative that doesn't make sense for the question... at most: `public static void Convert(this string str)` without the `string value` parameter. The OP has *one* string variable, you need *two* for your extension (the one you are calling the method on, and the one passed in as a parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your design is inverted, and your *interface* should be generic:

```
interface IConverter<T>
{
    void Convert(T value);
}
```

This would allow you to implement specific types in a specific way:

```
class BaseConverter<T> : IConverter<T>
{
    public void Convert(T value) 
    { /* some common way */ }
}

class StringConverter : IConverter<string>
{
    public void Convert(string value) 
    { /* strings get converted here */ }
}
```

And you would likely have a "factory" class which would provide the right converter instance:

```
class ConverterFactory
{
    // this is basically "poor man's" service locator,
    // but the same idea works with DI, where you
    // would register individual comparers 

    public IConverter<T> Create<T>()
    {
         // use a Dictionary, or add that
         // typeof(T) == typeof(string) check here
    }
}
```

This is similar to how, for example, [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined in .NET BCL, coupled with `Comparer<T>.Default`.

This is also the approach that would work better with DI, because your `IConverter<T>` depends on `T`, while having a single non-generic `IConverter` cannot tell DI which specific instance to inject.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do some type-checking within your generic-method.

```
public void Convert<T>(T value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T) == typeof(string) ? "String Method" : "Generic Method " + value);
}
```

However doing so omits all what is ment to be *generic*, doesn´t it? Having said this is not recommended.

Anyway only because two methods have the same *name* does not mean that they *are* equal, for the compiler `Convert(string)` and `Convert<T>(T)` are completely different methods. The interface however knows only the generic one, so when casting to it there is no knowledge on the string-method at all.

As Patrick already mentioned omit the cast or implement the string-method on the interface. Another - also dirty hack - would be to redirect the generic call to the string-method:

```
class Converter : IConverter
{
    public void Convert<T>(T value)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string) this.Convert((string) value);
        else Console.WriteLine("Generic Method " + value);
    }

    public void Convert(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("String Method " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, desperately want to keep the interface the same you can use a type check:

```
class Converter : IConverter
{
    public void Convert<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String Method " + (string)value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Generic Method " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as said by others, you can just add Convert(string) to IConverter.