# Can the C# generic methods be overloaded similar to C++ function overloading

Tags: c#, generics

Can C3 generic methods be overloaded similar to that of C++ function overloading.

Is the below code right way to overload the generic methods

```
class ReadFile<T> : IDisposable
{

    private FileStream fstream;
    private BinaryReader br;

    public ReadFile(string filename)
    {
       // do all the initialization
    }

    public void readValue(double val)
    {
       val = br.ReadDouble();
    }

    public void readValue(float val)
    {
       val = br.ReadSingle();
    }

    public void readValue(T val)
    {
       throw new Exception("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's called _template specialization_.  C# does not support it.

Comment: Is there no way to implement template specialization in C#?

Comment: No good solutions, but of course you can work around using one of 1) Reflection 2) `dynamic` 3) `if(typeof(T)==typeof(double)`

Comment: (btw assigning to a parameter like that has no effect, you need to use `ref` or `out`)

Comment: @veda Check answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c-sharp

Comment: See my answer below - template the method and not the class

Answer (score 3):

Instead of templating the class, you need to template the readValue method.  You can then use good ol' fashioned overloading to implement explicit types.  Don't forget to add the `out` keyword to your readValue parameters.  Quick console app demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rf = new ReadFile();

        double d;
        float f;
        int i;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format( "{1}: {0}", rf.readValue(out d), d ));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format( "{1}: {0}", rf.readValue(out f), f ));
        // note you don't have to explicitly specify the type for T
        // it is inferred
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format( "{1}: {0}", rf.readValue(out i), i ));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ReadFile
{
    // overload for double
    public string readValue(out double val)
    {
        val = 1.23;
        return "double";
    }

    // overload for float
    public string readValue(out float val)
    {
        val = 0.12f;
        return "float";
    }

    // 'catch-all' generic method
    public string readValue<T>(out T val)
    {
        val = default(T);
        return string.Format("Generic method called with type {0}", typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While some people argue against the use of generics for things like you describe, there are times when they are appropriate.  Nonetheless, there isn't a particularly convenient pattern for having different code execute for different types.  Probably the best approach is to have your `private static Action<T> readProc = InitReadProc;` and have the generic `ReadValue(T val)` call `readProc(val)`.  The `InitReadProc` method could look something like:

```
ReadFile<float>.readProc = readValue; // Binds to `float` overload
ReadFile<double>.readProc = readValue; // Binds to `double` overload
// etc. for all known overloads
if (readProc == InitReadProc) // The readProc of *this* type (T) didn't get set above
  throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("Type {0} not available", typeof(T));
else
  readProc();
```

Using this approach, the first time any attempt is made to call the generic `readValue` for any type, it will fill in the `readProc` delegates for all known types.  Any future attempt to call `readValue` on any such type will be dispatched via the delegate to the appropriate method.  Note that if desired one could offer a `ConfigureReadProc<T>(Action<T> proc)` method to allow consumers of the class to set up `ReadFile` methods for other types.  One could also if desired use Reflection to check whether type `T` supported a static `readValue(T)` method and, if so, attach the delegate to that.