# Declare Generic method in non generic interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, interface

Please consider this code:

```
public interface ImyInterface
{
    T GetEntity<T>(T t,int MasterID);
}
```

I declare a class name : `MyEntity` and it has a property with name `A_1`

```
public class BL_Temp : ImyInterface
{
    public MyEntity GetEntity<MyEntity>(MyEntity t, int MasterID)
    {
        t.A_1 = ""; //Error
        return t;
    }
}
```

the error is :

> 'MyEntity' does not contain a definition for 'A_1' and no extension method 'A_1' accepting a first argument of type 'MyEntity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does it possible to declare a generic method in non generic interface?

where is my mistakes?

thanks

---

**Edit1)**

Consider `MyEntity` declaration is :

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string A_1 {set; get;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, possible. but what is `A_1`? Are you aware that `MyEntity` is a generic parameter and not a `Type`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can declare, but your method will be generic and not a specific type. I mean  `MyEntity` is generic parameter, it is not your entity type.

You can add constraint to your entity like this, This allows you to to access `Entity` specific members..

```
public interface ImyInterface
{
    T GetEntity<T>(T t,int MasterID) where T : Entity;
}    

public class BL_Temp : ImyInterface
{
    public T GetEntity<T>(T t, int MasterID) where T : Entity
    {
        t.MyEntityProperty = "";
        return t;
    }
}
```

I know this is a sample code, but I felt worth mentioning that *Your method shouldn't lie*. Method name is `GetEntity` but it mutates the parameter which client may not be knowing (I'd say it lied). IMO you should atleast rename the method or don't mutate the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have class `MyEntity`, in this code

```
public MyEntity GetEntity<MyEntity>(MyEntity t, int MasterID)
```

`MyEntity` is treated as generic parameter. It looks like you want to achieve generic specialization. If so, read this: [How to do template specialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c-sharp)