# Use abstract generic type in c# and requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have follow classes:

```
public class File { }
public class DB { }

public abstract class Validator<T>
{
    T obj;
}

public class FileValidator : Validator<File>
{
}

public class DbValidator : Validator<DB>
{
}
```

In code I would like to have a ref to abstract class and create certain implementation depends on some condition (like factory).

```
public class Program
{
    static Validator getValidator()
    {
        //some condition here
        return new FileValidator<File>();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Validator v = getValidator();
    }
}
```

So, the compiler has a different opinion on this point

> Using the generic type 'Validator' requires 1 type arguments

Is there any workaround in this case? Unfortunately, File and DB can't have common interface.

Comment: If they don't have a common interface then how do you expect to call anything?

Comment: Validator<A> is not the same as Validator<B> - you need a Validator class. Why do you need a type in Validator?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/217110)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do template specialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a non-generic interface or abstract base-class:

```
public interface IValidator { ... }
public abstract class Validator<T> : IValidator
{

}
```

Now you can return `IValidator` from your method:

```
static IValidator getValidator()
{
    //some condition here
    return new FileValidator<File>();     
}

public static void Main()
{
    IValidator v = getValidator();
}
```

However be aware that there is **no** way for the compiler to infer the actual type, which is based upon a **runtime**-decision.

Apart from this your implementing classes should not be generic at all, only your abstract class should be:

```
public class FileValidator : Validator<File>
{
}

public class DbValidator : Validator<DB>
{
}
```