# Template Specialization Workaround

Tags: c#, generics

C# does [not support template specialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics). Is there a workaround? I am interested in achieving something similar to the c++ code below.

Thank you

```
    class C
    {
    public:
        template< typename T > void f() {} // no parameter function
        template<> void f<double>() {} // no parameter function
    };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do template specialization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600978/how-to-do-template-specialization-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Wyck No, it does not answer. `T` is not a method argument.

Comment: For those who don't read C++ on a regular basis but who might know a fair deal about C# features, can you explain *what* the C++ code achieves?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This is just an example. The actual code is complex. I cannot think of a different example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, you have to use dynamic dispatching

```
public class C
{
    public int DoWork<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            return DoWorkInt();

        return 13;
    }
    private int DoWorkInt() { return 42; }
}
```

> C# does not support explicit specialization; that is, a custom implementation of a template for a specific type.

From [Differences Between C++ Templates and C# Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/differences-between-cpp-templates-and-csharp-generics)